# rTorrent, too low memory usage ?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bittorrent, buffer

I want to know from more experienced rTorrent users how to tweak the .rtorrent.rc so that rTorrent will cache disk reading and writing (same as uTorrent does). 
I have set the max_memory_usage = 1GB but this amount is not used. I run 6 rTorrent instances on a Quad Core, 8 GB Ram machine and total used memory reported by htop is only ~500MB.

I need to use memory buffers cause disk IO activity is very high.

Comment: As noted in the answer by Chris, it's not clear what you're trying to cache: files of inactive torrents? Also, how much memory is currently used for buffers by Linux? You can tell from `top` or `free -m`.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used rTorrent since I found another similar torrent client (so my knowledge may be outdated now). When I used rTorrent it would only cache the blocks that were active at the time; either by leechers or the client itself write-caching. Unless something has changed, rtorrent will not cache inactive blocks.

The OS will cache some of the reads, and you may be able to tune the OS to cache more.

Comment: That would be interesting, but I use Linux for just 1 month, don't how to tune the mighty old Debian, lol.